# typo3 extbase: what happened to "forProperty" in a validator?

Tags: typo3, extbase

I have a model, lets call it Entry. And I created an EntryValidator to validate some fields. For example, the field "name" must not be empty. I can add an error like this:

```
public function isValid($entry) {

    if(!$entry->getName() || trim($entry->getName()) == ''){
        $this->addError('name must not be empty', 111);
    }
}
```

but how can I assign this error to the field "name" ? I tried to google it and what I find over and over is this:

```
$this->result->forProperty('name')->addError($error);
```

But this doesn't work any more (I'm using typo3 6.2). And I find to clues as to how to do this now.

Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by "not working"? No output in Fluid or validation doesn't happen? I'm using `$this->result->forProperty()` in TYPO3 7 and it works there. Also with TYPO3 6.2 I"m pretty sure it also works. Can you try to plaz with debugger and provide more info?

Answer (score 0):

you must add a return false and true to your isValid method.

```
public function isValid($entry) {

    if(!$entry->getName() || trim($entry->getName()) == ''){
        $this->addError('name must not be empty', 111);
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

or using with Error Object

```
 $this->result->forProperty('name')->addError(
                        new \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Error\Error(
                            $this->translateErrorMessage(
                                'key',
                                'ExtKey',
                                array()
                            ),
                            111)
                    );
```